# Why array is faster than dictionary in this test

Tags: c#, performance, nunit

Why is array faster in this test than dictionary looping 150 times to the end of array of size 150 is faster than accessing same key 150 times ?

I though it was due to optimization but i have disabled it

Please explain

```
[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]
    [Repeat(25)]
    [Test]
    public void DictionaryVSArray()
    {
        //array is faster from 0 up to 600 items;
        int collectionSize = 150;

        //populate array
        int[] array = new int[collectionSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < collectionSize; i++)
        {
            array[i] = i;
        }

        //populate dictionary
        Dictionary<int, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < collectionSize; i++)
        {
            dictionary.Add(i, i);

        }

        //dictionary measurement
        Stopwatch dictStopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        dictStopWatch.Start();

        for(int i = 0; i< collectionSize; i++)
        {
            var s = dictionary[collectionSize-1];
        }
        dictStopWatch.Stop();
        TimeSpan elapsedDict = dictStopWatch.Elapsed;


        //array measurement
        Stopwatch arrayStopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        arrayStopWatch.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < collectionSize; i++)
        {
            foreach (int item in array)
            {
                if (collectionSize-1 == item)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        arrayStopWatch.Stop();
        TimeSpan elapsedArray = arrayStopWatch.Elapsed;

        Assert.Greater(elapsedArray, elapsedDict, $"array was faster by {(elapsedDict - elapsedArray).TotalMilliseconds} miliseconds");
    }
```

Comment: Try a string-array/Dictionary. - there you will actually see some pretty difference. Int-comparison is quick, but string isn't.

Comment: but still, 150 X 150 loops vs 150 key accesses ?

Comment: Even if you turn off all optimisations, the JITTER still produces highly efficient code for array loops.

Comment: i think hash generation computation is slower than iterating 150 elements and that is the reason why

Comment: @IronHide, there is no hash computation for `int`s, the `int` value itself is its hash-code.

Answer (score 4):

I think your test is completely flawed and i get the opposite results.

For my setup

```
int collectionSize = 10000;

//populate array
_array = new int[collectionSize];

for (int i = 0; i < collectionSize; i++)
{
   _array[i] = i;
}

_dictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();
for (int i = 0; i < collectionSize; i++)
{
   _dictionary.Add(i, i);

}
```

**Code**

```
[Test("List", "", true)]
public object Test1(int[] input, int scale)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
   {
      foreach (int item in _array)
      {
         if (collectionSize - 1 == item)
         {
            break;
         }
      }
   }

   return null;
}

[Test("Dictionary", "", false)]
public object Test2(int[] input, int scale)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
   {
      var s = _dictionary[input[i]];
   }

   return null;
}
```

## Benchmarks

I run each test 100 times, *Garbage Collect* before each run, do a warm up runs, and generate 1000 random numbers between 0 - 255 to test on (in release mode).

```
┌──────────────────┬────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│        Test Mode │ Release (64Bit)                            │
│   Test Framework │ .NET Framework 4.7.1 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000) │
╞══════════════════╪════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│ Operating System │ Microsoft Windows 10 Pro                   │
│          Version │ 10.0.17134                                 │
├──────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│       CPU System │ Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz    │
│  CPU Description │ Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7       │
├──────────────────┼──────────┬──────────────────┬──────────────┤
│  Cores (Threads) │ 4 (8)    │     Architecture │ x64          │
│      Clock Speed │ 3401 MHz │        Bus Speed │ 100 MHz      │
│          L2Cache │ 1 MB     │          L3Cache │ 8 MB         │
└──────────────────┴──────────┴──────────────────┴──────────────┘
```

## Results

```
┌── Standard input ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Value      │   Average │   Fastest │   Cycles │ Garbage │ Test │    Gain │
├── Scale 1,000 ────────────────────────────────────────────── 0.784 sec ──┤
│ Dictionary │ 13.680 µs │ 13.208 µs │ 50.621 K │ 0.000 B │ N/A  │ 99.76 % │
│ List       │  5.706 ms │  5.485 ms │ 19.406 M │ 0.000 B │ Base │  0.00 % │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: of course  this is not the case if there are more element but anything below 150 array wins

Comment: @IronHide I run the same test with 100 elements and its still factors faster to use a dictionary, and it is reproducible even with 10 elements

Comment: so you basically have identical test but do not observe the issue on smaller collections ? interesting but i don't see a stopwatch in your test maybe put them in the test methods to make sure identical test

Comment: @IronHide hi, i use a benchmarking library, this is the most reliable way to test things like this. Take a look at BenchmarkDotNet, hours of fun

Answer (score 1):

The Dictionary has a hastable for the keys, to have a quick access to it. And finding something by hash is mostly quicker than comparing the content. But in your case, integer values are quickly compared, and as you just have 150*150 elements (22500), this is taking nearly no time, neither for dictionary, nor for array.

Try something arround 1000 * 1000.

How much ms do you actually measure?

Also you should maybe "search" for the i-value of the loop, not always with the same "collectionSize". Maybe compiler is making optimizations there too.

Comment: optimizations are disabled as you can see above method header

Answer (score 0):

in secound stopwatch you have an if  condition thats may occures in starting of foreach repeatation.